# call parent function of mocked class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have got the following question.

```
class A
{
    public function isNew()
    {
        return ($this->ID == 0);
    }
}

    class B extends A  
    {
      //Some functions  
    }
```

Now I want to mock Class B. So I have got some statements

```
$oMockedStm = $this->getMockBuilder('B')->getMock();        
$oMockedStm->expects($this->any())->method('someMethod')->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));           
$oMockedStm->expects($this->any())->method('anotherMethod')->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));
```

Now When I do

```
$this->assertTrue($oMockedStm->isNew());
```

I get the Error: Failed asserting that null is true.

How can this be. The function always returns true of false.

Does it have something to do with the fact that you can't call parent method of mocked objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I didn't want to mock the whole class. Only specific functions.
So what you so when defining your mock object is you use the `setMethods()`  function to specify the specific functions you want to mock.

So like this:

```
$oMockedStm = $this->getMockBuilder('B')
                ->setMethods(array('someMethod','anotherMethod'))
                ->getMock();
```